# A way to use Python which I don't know

Tags: python

In this quicksort function:

```
def qsort2(list):
    if list == []: 
        return []
    else:
        pivot = list[0]
        # can't understand the following line
        lesser, equal, greater = partition(list[1:], [], [pivot], [])
    return qsort2(lesser) + equal + qsort2(greater)

def partition(list, l, e, g):
    if list == []:
        return (l, e, g)
    else:
        head = list[0]
        if head < e[0]:
            return partition(list[1:], l + [head], e, g)
        elif head > e[0]:
            return partition(list[1:], l, e, g + [head])
        else:
            return partition(list[1:], l, e + [head], g)
```

I don't understand the sentence below the comment. Can someone tell me what is the meaning of this sentence here?

Comment: Incidentally, it's not a great idea to use "list" as a variable name- "list" is already the name of something built-in to python, and redefining that name can lead to strange behavior in some cases. Your code will probably work, but you really want to develop careful habits now, rather than find the edge case the hard way later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It unpacks a tuple into three variables.

```
def foo():
    return (1, 2, 3)

a, b, c = foo()
print(a) # prints "1"
print(b) # prints "2"
print(c) # prints "3"
```

Comment: Thanks, but partition consumes 4 items, here we only have 3, how about the first one?

Comment: It's about what `partition` *returns*, which is a 3-tuple (`return (l, e, g)`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, so it doesn't matter about about the first items.

Comment: It is not related to the arguments you pass to `partition`.